# how to fetch value from a drop down menu filter another list using that value

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to create a drop down list with values from the database and using this value to filter another list

```
class Venues(models.Model):
    venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rent = models.IntegerField()
    parking_area = models.IntegerField()
```

from this model I want to obtain a `<select>` tag, populated from a list of `place` with no duplicates, and to use the selected value in order to filter the `Venues` for that `place`.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the Django admin or on a view?

Comment: in view so it can be shown in HTML

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create a custom form in django with database values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969051/how-create-a-custom-form-in-django-with-database-values)